# Brush looks blocky/low resolution when painting textures (Pic included)

Tags: texture-painting

I'm sure this is something silly I'm doing wrong here but I can't find a solution at all. My texture is 2048x2048 and I'm trying to paint details on it.

When I draw the brush looks blocky/pixelated though. The stroke looks like it has a low resolution. The smaller the radius the worse it looks and painting side to side looks better than when painting up and down.

Here is a picture:
[image]

If someone could try to help me out here, that would be great.

Comment: That is obviously pixelation. I can't tell why its happening from the information you gave though.

Comment: Can you show us the unwrapping (UV layout) or the resulting texture? My first guess would be that you are only drawing on a very small section of the file.

Comment: Looking at it, yeah it is only a small part of the UVs. I tried increasing the size, but only at 8192 x 8192 is the detail level where I want it. Somehow that sounds to me like it would be to be too big. Here is an image of how the UV layout looks: http://i.imgur.com/GLY1UMh.png

Comment: Do you need this resolution everywhere or only there? In the latter case, just increase the size of this one piece in the UV layout. You may also be able to use the space a little more efficiently if you rearrange the islands by hand. 8k^2 is quite big for a texture, although it can still work.

Comment: Did you tried custom your Brush-Curve in Tool sheft (left pannel, T) ?
It gives more smooth/hard painting.

Comment: Really need to show the uv map as it relates to the mapping here, but probably means you need a better uv map if you are needing more pixels here.

Answer (score 0):

in texture paint mode go to your left panel and go to options and deselect occlude in project paint

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  Can you please elaborate why this will help, and what the problem is?

Comment: "Options" on left panel is a very broad term... I don't see anything that says "options"